# Find all pixels on a circle

Tags: pixel, geometry

I need to find pixels laying on a circle centered on point (0,0). Right now I do this by using formulas:

x = round(r * cos(angle))

y = round(r * sin(angle))

and my angle takes values from 0 to 2 Pi.

However this is not producing accurate results. For example, it gives point (1,1) for diameter 1 and also for diameter 2. How to avoid it?

Comment: What values do you get if don't use `round`? You should investigate how the `round` method works in whatever language you're using - some use [banker's rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer).

Comment: I've tried rounding down to the nearest integer by simple casting double to an integer. Also, I tried adding 0.5 to get an exact rounding. I've also tried to find closest pixel to given coordinates by using Pythagorean theorem. Unfortunately In each attempt, for some pixels, rounded distance to the point (0,0) do not match diameter. I need to find those pixels for growing diameter value, so probably I will just check all pixels and place each one in corresponding class basing on its distance to the center.